# Mac OS X backup to NAS Server - Time Machine or other

Tags: macos, backup, nas, time-machine, synology

I just bought Synology DiskStation and I want to backup my files. I was thinking about Time Machine and I started to make this happen but I found out that Time Machine backup whole Mac and not just folders which I choose, right? I bought 1TB HDD for NAS so I don't want to backup my whole disc in MacBook but just folders I choose. If I still use Time Machine I have a few questions. What would be result of Time Machine in backup drive? Would it be similar structure to MacBook or would it be some kind of extension which can only be used by Time Machine? And if I have Bootcamp, the Windows partion would be backup too or not?

If I would go another way than Time Machine I saw in other questions alternatives but I am not sure what is best for my goal. So what is best for backup only choosen folders from Mac to NAS and with similar features as Time Machine? Maybe to have possibilities to set time each date to sync changes (so incremental backup or what is name of this). I don't think that Cloud Station from Synology would be for me. I don't want to one folder be sync but to folders which I choose. And for performance I think it would be better if backup was not sync but just every night increment after daywork. Thanks for help

Comment: My 2 cents: don't solely rely on backups on a NAS. Even though things like crypto ransomware are Windows-only at the moment, backups in the network are not easily secured from being wiped, especially not home grown solutions. Time Machine has made backing up (and, also important: *restoring*) soooo easy; better spent some money on dedicated backup disks.

Comment: Synology can support time machine backup. Assuming the latest DSM (5.2) It is located on Control Panel - File Services. Under there there is a Mac File Service. Simply enable that, and then set a dedicated "Time machine" folder, and you can point your mac to that and it should work like your normal time machine backup. (I happened to own the same NAS, I just don't use that feature because I don't have a mac)

Comment: **Darius:** I don't have problem with enable it. I have another questions about it. I know I can get working easily but I am not sure if it would fit for my goals. 
**Arjan:** Thanks. I'll think about backup to another storage but for now I am looking for best solution with my NAS.